# Returninf from python function

Tags: python, function, return

Why this is not working? Python says that `b` is undefined.

```
def funkcija(a):
    b=a*2
    return b
a=int(input("broj"))
funkcija(a)
print(b)
```

Comment: b is right now a local variable and its scope is within the function. That's why you can't access it.   `b = funkcija(a)`  assigned function return to b and you are set to go.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed your formatting first - I hope i get your code correct:

```
def funkcija(a): 
   b=a*2 
   return b 

a=int(input("broj")) 
funkcija(a)
print(b)
```

Now anwser:
b is undefined because you declare it in function (it is only avaiable there). What you want to do is assign return value to your variable b

```
b=funkcija(a)
```

So your code will look like this:

```
def funkcija(a): 
   b=a*2 
   return b 

a=int(input("broj")) 
b=funkcija(a)
print(b)
```

If you don't use 'b' anywhere else, you could also:

```
print(funkcija(a))
```

This will print returned value by your function.

---

As @BrainO mentioned - variable b has no use in funkcija. You can replace your code with nice one-liner:

```py
def funkcija(a):
   return a*2
```

Comment: And in fact, there's no reason for the local variable `b` in the function. It can be a one-liner:`return a * 2`. Just to make your point again, the `b` within the function's indented code has nothing to do with the `b` that's printed at the top level.

Answer (score 0):

look at your code , variable b is not defined.

```
def funkcija(a):
    b=a*2
    return b

a=int(input("broj"))
funkcija(a)
print(b)
```

do you mean your code like this?

```
b = 0
def funkcija(a):
    b=a*2
    return b

a=int(input("broj"))
funkcija(a)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

`b` is defined inside the function : `b=a*2`. So, you need to assign `b=funkcija(a)` as this will return `b` which is 2x the input.

```
def funkcija(a):
    b=a*2
    return b
a=int(input("broj"))
b=funkcija(a)
print(b)
```